# How to get that list of all the available Terraform Resource types for Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I started learning Terraform recently. For `google` and `google-beta` providers, I want to check/list all the available resource type, but I am not receiving any valuable informations. Hashicorp page - [Command: terraform providers schema](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/providers/schema) does not seem to provide more information here.

Steps I followed Google Cloud Shell

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir tf-temp
$ cd tf-temp
$ touch main.tf
$ terraform init
$ terraform providers schema
The `terraform providers schema` command requires the `-json` flag.


Usage: terraform [global options] providers schema -json

  Prints out a json representation of the schemas for all providers used
  in the current configuration.

$
$ terraform providers schema -json
{"format_version":"1.0"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key thing to note in the documentation is the phrase at the end of the opening sentence (emphasis mine):

> The `terraform providers schema` command is used to print detailed schemas for **the providers used in the current configuration**.

There are a few different ways that a provider can be "used in the current configuration", but the most direct way is to explicitly declare [Provider Requirements](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements) in your root module. If you want to obtain the schemas for the `hashicorp/google` and `hashicorp/google-beta` providers then you can declare those requirements in the following way:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.27.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "4.27.0"
    }
  }
}
```

You don't absolutely need the exact version constraints like I showed above -- you could use a less specific version constraint or no constraint at all if you just want to get the latest -- but I included it just to show how you can guide Terraform to select the version of the provider whose schemas you want.

You can then run `terraform init` to install the provider and record the selected versions in the dependency lock file, before running `terraform providers schema -json` to see the schemas extracted from those providers.

```
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/google-beta versions matching "4.27.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/google versions matching "4.27.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/google-beta v4.27.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google-beta v4.27.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/google v4.27.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v4.27.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
```

```
$ terraform providers schema -json | jq
{
  "format_version": "1.0",
  "provider_schemas": {
    "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google": {
      "provider": {
        "version": 0,
        "block": {
          "attributes": {
            "access_approval_custom_endpoint": {
              "type": "string",
```

(...truncated because it's too long for a reasonable Stack Overflow answer)

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for someone who want quick answer:

```
terraform init
terraform providers schema -json | jq  -rM '.provider_schemas[].resource_schemas|keys[]'
```